# waiting on selector input on playwright

Tags: css-selectors, playwright

So Im having a problem with playwright.
Im trying to fill an input field with a certain placeholder.

using:

```
await page.waitForSelector('input[placeholder="Text"]', {
        state: "visible",
    });
await page.fill('input[placeholder="Text"]', "Blabla");
```

And im timing out because its not visible.

The input field im trying to fill is rendered only when a user click on a certain button on the screen that toggles the input field.

For example:

```
option 1
option 2
```

when the user clicks on option 2 an input field becomes visible to collect data from the user.
so its not always visible on the screen.

When im always showing the input field, without the conditional rendering its not a problem, so im guessing the fact im rendering it only when a certain option is selected and its not always visible is my problem.

how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure its the best method but when I needed to check if something was visible I evaluated the selectors first, got the class, then checked if it had the keyword that was added when it was visible.
in my case I did this

```
  //i need to force the navbar to close when it stays open 
  let navbarClass: string = await page.$eval('[name="navbar"]', el => el.getAttribute('class'));
  if(navbarClass.includes('unfolded')) {      //unfolded was added when its open
    await page.locator('<the input selector>').click();
  }
```

the page.$eval can get lots of different attributes of the selector and hopefully there is something in your code that will help determine its open.